# Android Voice to text: cursor to end of the line

Tags: android, text, cursor, voice-recognition

When using the voice to text in Android, how do you make the cursor go to the end of the line. Also, My voice to text replaces existing text with new text when the VTT is pressed a second time.

```
textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spoken_text);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                textViewResult.setText(result.get(0));
                textViewResult.setText(result.get(1));
            }
```

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to get used to the format here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the cursor to the end of the line (I assume you are talking about an EditText element) you can do

```
EditText voiceText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_id); 
voiceText.setSelection(voiceText.getText().length());
```

Regarding how to update your text instead of replacing it requires more info about how you store the text and such.

One recommendation could be to look at something like [this](https://www.varvet.com/blog/voice-to-text-arch-android/) blogpost, showcasing how to do voice to text with android architecture components.

Comment: It is a textView, but will do the same thing

Comment: A TextView does not have a cursor. And voice to text has really nothing to do with cursors either. The RecognitionListener only outputs strings.

Comment: So, do you advise an EditText instead? I have tried both an EditText and A TextView and get the same results. Further, how do I get the flashing cursor to the end of the string produced by the RecognitionListener?

Comment: It depends on what you want. A cursor indicates that you like to edit the text manually as well - then surely you'd like and EditText. If not, TextView is the natural choice.